# How to hide the LatePoint Premium Notification from the client front page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

without purchasing the plugin  How to hide the LatePoint Premium Notification from the client front page?

I didn't find the class name to hide it using css, is there any method need to be applied to solve this problem?

I tried css and that didn't worked for me in this case